# Google Login Plugin plugin does not allow users from multiple domains

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using using Jenkins' [Google login plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Login+Plugin) for user authentication. I've installed and configured the plugin as mentioned in documentation and working as well. However users from only one google app domain can login to jenkins and access it([jira link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32536)). We have users from couple of domains. Another issue with this plugin is- not able to control user authorizations. All users can do anything. I've attached screenshot showing jenkins google login plugin configuration

[image]

Is there any workaround or alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.3 (November 21st, 2016) the google login plugin allow multiple domains separated by comma.

Check the changelog:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+Login+Plugin

And the PR:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-login-plugin/pull/3

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/permissions-overview#understanding-authentication-for-your----end-users) that's not possible and the only suggestion is to set "Allow anyone with a Google account" if you are using multiple domains:

> **Understanding authentication for your end-users**
>
> ...
>
> 2. Allow only members of a Google Apps domain to access the application. This is ideal for “intranet” applications where access is
>      limited to the users in your domain.
>
>    This method can only restrict to a single Google Apps domain. **This
>      will not work if you use** [multiple domains with Google apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182452). *If you are
>      using multiple domains*, then select **“Allow anyone with a Google
>      account**” and extend your application code to restrict access to
>      end-users that are from your set of Google Apps domains. Your
>      application can use the value of the [user_organization](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/) of the
>      signed-in user (rather than parsing the email address) to determine
>      the domain name of the user.

Also, this issue is already registered in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32536 and it is still **Open and Unresolved**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was expecting if there is any alternative to these limitations but apparently there is not.